# How to save multiple checked checkbox of recycler view in firebase?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

`

```
public class moodspojo {
    private int moodimg;
    private String mood;
    private boolean moodcheck;

    public moodspojo(int moodimg, String mood,boolean moodcheck) {
        this.moodimg = moodimg;
        this.mood = mood;
        this.moodcheck=moodcheck;
    }

    public int getMoodimg() {
        return moodimg;
    }

    public String getMood() {
        return mood;
    }

    public boolean isMoodcheck() {
        return moodcheck;
    }
}
```

I have two activities as shown below for which I have used recycler view. I want to save **all the values** to firebase which are checked by the user when user click on image button in the top right corner.
I want to save those checkbox values along with its image and name.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 0):

You can have boolean variable for check box in model, and use the value from model to check and unCheck checkBox in the RecyclerView.
When click on check box just flip the value in model also.

Comment: I have shared pojo above. Please let me know what should I do

Comment: So you already have a boolean for checkbox in pojo.

Now you can create one create setter method for checkbox 
and call it when you click or change check box to update the  value of checkbox,  

public boolean setMoodcheck(boolean isCheck) {
         moodcheck = isCheck;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Add a public default constructor to your class `public moodspojo(){/* No code needed */}` and change the name of `isMoodcheck()` to `getMoodcheck()`

And then to store it into firebase, use this code

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().setVaue(moodspojo.class);
```

You can read more about how to read and write to firebase realtime database over here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

PS: Please follow convention. First letter of class should be capital

Thanks